# How can I automatically publish my blog feed on my Facebook page?

Tags: facebook-pages, blog, feeds

We have got a blog for our company in which we post about issues related to our job; this enables us to share our posts with a limited number of people who directly visit our blog.

Besides, we have a Facebook page for our company which has a great number of fans who also could be good audience for our blog posts. Sharing our blog posts manually in our Facebook page is a burden, and we need a way to share our blog feed automatically on our Facebook page. But is there a way to share new posts on our Facebook page automatically?

UPDATE: As Eddie correctly stated, I should mention that we've used Drupal as our blog content management system, but I'm not specifically asking this question for a Drupal system and I prefer a more general solution.

Comment: Have you tried anything? A [simple Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=automatically+post+blog+to+facebook+page) shows me a plethora of options.

Comment: What's your blogging software? Some of them offer the ability to post to Facebook.

Comment: We're using Drupal. Thanks for proposing one of those options here Eddie.

Comment: That's important information that you should add to your question. Comments are, by their nature, impermanent.

Comment: Absolutely Eddie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are dozens of solutions to this.

Facebook used to let you use an RSS feed to create Notes, but they closed that door a long time ago.

[This If-This-Then-That recipe](https://ifttt.com/recipes/5980) (among many others) will create a link post on your Facebook Page Wall with every new post in your RSS feed.

Answer (score 3):

Since you use Drupal, you can also use [Drupal for Facebook](http://drupal.org/project/fb). It is a module that you have to install into your Drupal website. With this module, you can automatically publish your new content to Facebook and allow Facebook users to connect via Facebook Connect.

Comment: tnx Abed for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

This [Zapier Zap](https://zapier.com/z/Cvn/zapbook/rss/facebook/3796/post-rss-feed-to-facebook-page/) will let you share to your company page. You can also share to multiple pages as well which might be a benefit if you have lots of different Facebook pages to manage sharing.

[image: RSS to Facebook Page]

Disclosure: I run Zapier, but I still think it's a great solution. :)

Comment: Good job man, I should give it a try

Answer (score -1):

Yes. All you need is to login to PostRSS. It allows to post RSS to Facebook.